# Can I connect 2 VGA monitors to a surface laptop 2?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, mini-displayport

I have 2 VGA monitors that I want to connect to my surface laptop 2. I would like to be able to extend, not just mirror, the screens so that I have different things on each monitor. I have 2 VGA to HDMI adapters. I was wondering if I plugged those into a dual HDMI to mini display port I could achieve what I wanted. Alternatively, I wondered whether I could put 1 display through the USB 3 port? Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.

What you want is a USB to VGA adapter (they are cheap...about $15 each on Amazon). You'll need two of them for two monitors. They do make ones that connect to TWO VGA ports that are more expensive, but maybe it's worth it to you [here's a link if you want to check it out](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004ETETZK).

Comment: Thats a nice link to a usb to serial cable ... Although you are right, there are usb docks that have multiple monintor output support. Google for "USB dual monitor dock".

Comment: USB rather than miniDP?

Comment: @TaxpayersMoney you can absolutely use the mini dp output too.

Comment: @TaxpayersMoney I have found a miniDP to ONE VGA port adpater, but not one that supports two VGA simultaneously. They do make miniDP to dual HDMI though...so the bandwidth capability is there, but there must not be much of a market for it. If it were me...I'd buy several different options and then return the ones that don't work...